# jQuery UI Calendar widget to change date when changing year or month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI calendar widget with the month and year drop downs, like show here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Apparently some people pick a day, then open the widget again, pick a year and a month and let it close. The issue is that picking the year and month doesn't change the year and month of the date being entered, only the one being displayed to the user.

Is there a way to have the year and month have an immediate effect on the date, so that if I have the date 22/06/2012 and chose 1990, it'll automatically go to 22/06/1990.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set trigger to this event `onChangeMonthYear`.

For example:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        if(inst.currentYear != inst.drawYear || inst.currentMonth != inst.drawMonth) {
          $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(year, month - 1, inst.selectedDay));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's really helpful. My only issue is that I let the internationalization files select the date format, so I would be breaking the abstraction by doing that, and furthermore, I need to update a hidden input that contains the date in iso format. I'm trying to figure if there's a straightforward way to do this.

Comment: You can use something like this:
`d = new Date(Date.parse(year + '-' + month + '-' + inst.selectedDay));
d.format('yy-mm-dd');`

So you can set it to the format you'd like to.

Comment: I found a working solution building on top of yours and updated the answer accordingly. Thank you! :)